# "user" is not set when parsing a data-dict to a Django form, but all other fields are

Tags: django, django-forms

Say I have the following

```py
#models.py

class MyModel(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=2048)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    used = models.BooleanField(default = True)
```

and my form

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Wishlist
        exclude = [
            "user","date_added"
        ]
```

If I try to create an instance like (note, I have omitted the `if request.method="POST"` etc. for clarity)

```py
def myView(request):
    user = request.user

    instance = MyModel(user=user)
    data = {"link":link,"date_added":domain,"user":user}
    form = MyModelForm(data=data)
    form.save()
```

the `link` and `date_added` is written to the database, but the `user` field is empty.

If I set the `user` to the instance after the form is created like

```py
def myView(request):
    user = request.user

    instance = MyModel(user=user)
    data = {"link":link,"date_added":domain}
    form = MyModelForm(data=data)
    form.save(commit=False)
    form.instance.user = user  #Setting the user here
    form.save()
```

It works like a charm.

How come, I cannot set the `user` in the data-dict, and is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come, I cannot set the user in the data-dict.

A form will ignore all fields that it does not have to process. This makes the webserver more secure: here we ensure that the user can not create a `MyModel` for another user.

If thus a field belongs to the `excluded` attribute, or not in the `fields` attribute from the `Meta` class, then the form will *not* set the corresponding model object attribute.

You did not specify the `instance` to the form:

```
def myView(request):
    user = request.user
    instance = MyModel(user=user)
    data = {"link":link,"date_added":domain}
    form = MyModelForm(data=data, instance=instance)
    form.save()
```

Comment: `A form will ignore all fields that it does not have to process.` - can you elaborate that/do you have a link to that, since `link` and `date_added` is set, but only `user` isnt? I've tried to search through Djagons Form documentation, but I struggle to find their class-specific-docs e.g their Form-class docs? And how come

Comment: @CutePoison: the `link` is set because it is not in the `exclude` field, so that field *will* be processed. For the `date_added`, this is *not* done by the `Form`, but as `default=...` in your `date_added` field.

Comment: Aah, in that way. Thanks a lot - I'll accept the answer when SO allows me (still some time left)